# Is there any way to turn on my "Out of Office" automatic replies when an event in the calendar is marked "out of office"?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, out-of-office

I have recurring events that cause me to be out of the office on a regular basis. I have updated my calendar to reflect that I will be out of the office.

Currently I use the "Out of Office" automatic replies. I don't want to have to turn them on every time I will be gone - especially since I know far in advance and it is a regularly recurring event.

Is there any way to turn on my "Out of Office" automatic replies when an event in the calendar is marked "out of office"?

Note: I am currently using Outlook 2010, but I could upgrade to 2013 if it has this functionality.

Comment: That certainly would be a nice feature. It definitely is not a feature Outlook allows and I have not be able to find any code or add-ins which would facilitate it.

Comment: would be possible by a script that runs on every mail arrival (which also checks calendar) but would mean the client is on.

Comment: NB: the old link is deprecated, but you can still (after all this time) vote for the feature: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/15f75a89-db1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f80e8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not possible. Out-of-office replies are sent by Exchange. There is no Exchange feature that reads calendar events in users mailboxes.

Calendar reminders are sent by Outlook, there is no link between the two that can be turned on.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a walkthrough, but it does provide the steps required in order to get it working.  If anyone actually completes this, I would love to see them post it.

Use the Rules Wizard.  On every inbound mail, you will want to run a script.

The script you will want to run is an Outlook VBA script, which will perform the following actions:

- [Check for any current meetings](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?175221-Finding-current-appointment-in-Outlook)
- For every current MeetingItem object found, you will want to check the `busyStatus` of the object to see if it matches `olOutOffice`
- Finally, [set your out of office status appropriately](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/automating-out-of-office/) or reply back with a custom "I am in a meeting" message.

Additional References:

- http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo/RDOOutOfOfficeAssistant.htm
- http://www.outlook-answers.com/microsoft/Outlook-Program-VBA/29286942/automatic-activation-of-outofoffice-mesage.aspx
- http://www.slipstick.com/outlook-developer/code-samples/set-reminder-meeting-request/

Good luck and godspeed!

Comment: But this won't work if the client machine is shut down, right?  I think the OP wants the replies to happen completely automagically.

Comment: How about a script which runs when you exit Outlook? Which finds the next `olOutOffice` event, then sets up Automatic Replies with appropriate "during this time range". Means you must log back in in-between each OOO event.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: it's possible "if you have an e-mail account on a Microsoft Exchange Server, the server can apply rules to your messages even if you don't have Outlook running" ([office.microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook-help/about-managing-messages-with-rules-HP001052476.aspx)). But I'm guessing the OP doesn't.