# Automatic reply in Outlook when out of office

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, vba, appointments, out-of-office

For my e-mail account on a Microsoft Exchange Server, I would like that, for each email received where the following two condition are met :

- I am in the to: or in cc:
- I have an "out of office" appointment in my outlook calendar during the time of reception of that email.

An automatic reply is sent to the sender with a message to say that I am out of office and that I will be back on the day /time where my out of office appointment ends.

Ideally, the solution should not be based on a local macro in MS Outlook (because I would need to run it each time I close and open Outlook and because I need to keep my computer on when I am out of office) but can be somehow set on the server.

I saw a post of 10 years ago, basically equivalent to this question : [Is there any way to turn on my "Out of Office" automatic replies when an event in the calendar is marked "out of office"?](https://superuser.com/questions/571193/is-there-any-way-to-turn-on-my-out-of-office-automatic-replies-when-an-event-i)

Comment: Just wondering have you had a chance to check the reply provided earlier and see if it helped?

Answer (score 2):

It's still not possible from either the Outlook client side or the Exchange server side. You can post to the feedback portal to request this feature via https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/ .

As a workaround, I'd recommend setting up the automatic replies from Outlook on the web instead so that the OOF event can be created at the same time:
[image]